# My inner join doesn't work Unknown column

Tags: mysql, sql, join, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to do an innerjoin but when I do this in Sql it says: Unknown column 'evenement.id' in 'on clause'. How can I make this work?

SQL join:

```
SELECT *
FROM `evenement` INNER JOIN
     `evenementontvanger`
     ON  `evenement.id` = `evenementontvanger.idEvent`
ORDER BY `id`
```

my tables are->

Evenement:

```
id
title
start
startdate
starttime
end
endtime
enddate
url
allDay
description
color
```

evenementontvanger: 
id
idEvent
idWerknemer
idProject
idKlant
idTaak

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to quote each identifier individually;

```
ON  `evenement`.`id` = `evenementontvanger`.`idEvent`
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have `evenement.id` between backticks.  That makes it a single identifier, rather than two connected by a `.`.  The following fixes the query and adds table aliases and fixes the next problem which is the ambiguous column in the `order by`:

```
SELECT *
FROM evenement e INNER JOIN
     evenementontvanger ev
     ON  e.id = e.idEvent
ORDER BY e.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need the tick marks around each identifier. If you put them around a combined identifier, it will interpret it as a single identifier, i.e. there is no field named `evenement.id`.

```
SELECT *
FROM `evenement` INNER JOIN
     `evenementontvanger`
     ON  `evenement`.`id` = `evenementontvanger`.`idEvent`
ORDER BY `id`
```

Answer (score -1):

The ID field would be set twice you need to specify the fields you want to retrieve as they have conflicting names

```
SELECT `evenement`.`id`, `evenementontvanger`.`id`
    FROM `evenement` INNER JOIN
         `evenementontvanger`
         ON  `evenement`.`id` = `evenementontvanger`.`idEvent`
    ORDER BY `evenement`.`id`
```

Comment: Not sure if this is incorrect as it's being marked down?

Answer (score -1):

You need have the same column names in both tables in order to apply the inner join. Try renaming either of the column names. Look up the example on http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Comment: You don't need the same column names for any kind of join. Inner joins depend on compatible data types and  (in the case of equi-joins) matching values, not on column names.